# C++ 生成・解放が重いオブジェクトをconstつきで関数に渡すときの参照渡しのチェック

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler

C++ において、 std::set など生成・解放が重いオブジェクトをconstつきで関数に渡すとき、参照にし忘れることがあります。これをチェックするような既存のコードレビューツールやコンパイラオプション(いまはGCC 7.3 を使っています)は何かないのでしょうか？
気を付けていてもコードレビューで注意されることが多いため、困っています。

- 「自分で気を付ける」以外の回答を望みますが、現状それしか手段がない場合も、それを教えてください。
- 何か理由があってそのような既存のツールがない、という場合も、その理由を教えて下さると参考になります。

Comment: 例えば[Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/)とか使えるのでは？ [C/C++のソースコードをCppcheckで静的解析してみよう](https://www.clear-code.com/blog/2016/2/3.html), [2.8 passedByValue - Cppcheckの使い方](https://www.hiroom2.com/2015/07/13/cppcheck%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9/#sec-2-8), [why cppcheck say "Function parameter should be passed by reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21305132/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

コピーコンストラクタ(と代入オペレータ)を消すのが確実です。

たとえば `std::set<int>` をコピーしたくないなら、`std::set<int>`を継承したクラスを定義して、コピーコンストラクタと`operator=`を消します。

```cpp
class IntSet : public std::set<int> {
public:
  IntSet();
  // 必要に応じて他のコンストラクタも定義

  IntSet(const IntSet&) = delete;
  IntSet& operator=(const IntSet&) = delete;
};
```

これで、参照ではない引数のためにインスタンスのコピーが必要になると、コンパイルエラーになります。

意図的にコピーする必要が出てきた場合は、`IntSet clone() const` のようなメンバ関数を足します。